# trapezoid fitting in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, contour

I am using OpenCV to do segmentation using methods like grabcut, watershed. Then use findContours to obtain the contour. The actual contour I would like to obtain is a trapezoid and the functions approxPolyDP and convexHull cannot do this. Can somebody give me some hits? Maybe there are other methods rather than segmentation to obtain it? I can think of edge detection using methods like Canny but the result is not good because of unconstrained background. A lot of segments have to be connected and it is kind of hard.

The sample image is also attached (the first one--human shoulder). I would like to find the contour and the location of where the contour/edge changes its direction, that is the human shoulders. As in the second image, the right corner point can change resulting in a trapezoid.

1.jpg:  original image
2.jpg:  the contour is labelled by hand
3.jpg:  fitted lines

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByQ8kRZEPlqXUUZyaGtpSkJDeXc&usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: Post some test images to better illustrate your problem. Your title is also misleading. If you are trying to segment trapezoid from an image, then say that. But as it is, your question is unclear.

Comment: Please see uploaded images. Thanks